# Make all windows open in the center of the screen on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, display, kde, window-manager, window

I've looked everywhere in the window management settings, and I can't find a setting to change the window placement setting like there is in Compiz Config Settings Manager. I want all of the windows to open in the center of the display **that has the mouse on it, not the one that has the selected window**. (I usually have 2 displays connected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kubuntu you can choose the placement of opening windows under

`System Settings`>`Workspaces`>`Window Mangement`>`Window Behavior`>`Advanced-tab`> `Placement`